# Playback log files in can bus

Tags: stm32, can, logic-analyzer

I'm using MCP2515 CAN Bus controller and I'm connecting between two boards successfully. 
I have bough a can bus analyzer Ksaver, which allows to playback log files.

1. I connect the logic analyzer DB9 to one board that is connected to MCP2515 Transciever
2. I playback the log file
3. I expect to get a simulated version of a tx can data
4. I expect to get data on the board that is simulated

The problem is the board is setup as an rx, but I don't get any callbacks fired for getting a message while playing back the can bus.

Comment: Is there any traffic on the bus when you measure it with a scope?

Comment: No there is no traffic. But My another question, Am I understanding it correctly ? The playback functionality should simulate a transmitter  for example ?

Comment: I think you are probably better off asking this directly to Kvaser support.

Comment: The video shows a column for direction with only Rx shown implies to me that you can enable the log to capture Tx as well when selected.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I did the same, I modified the log file to Tx and nothing is captured by the board